# Easy way / plug-in to scroll to the next section using arrow keys in Angular

Tags: angularjs, scroll

I have multiple sections (each taking full-screen) in the landing page. And I want to take users to the next section using 1. arrow key (down arrow) AND 2. mouse scroll. Any way to do this easily in Angular? Having trouble implementing jQuery based codes... Thanks!

NOTE: all three sections share the same URL

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly to your edit

Comment: please accept my answer if you found it to be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$document.bind` to bind to keyboard events like so:

```
function handler(event) {
  console.debug(event)
};

// or bind/unbind instead of on/off
// if using just jqLite 
$document.on("keypress", handler);

//to deregister handler
$document.off("keypress", handler);
```

Since you want to use the same URL, you're best off using Angular UI Router and [nested views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views). Note that you can use the same controller with nested views or optionally provide a separate controller with each view. If you want to introduce the complexity of using separate controllers you can have a parent controller which facilitates navigation (e.g. for your "view" state) and use $rootScope.$broadcast to communicate with child views (e.g. "view.child1", "view.child2", etc..) (although I prefer more explicit mechanisms like postal.js for this scenario - [more on using postal with angular here](http://jonathancreamer.com/an-angular-event-bus-with-postal-js/)) [`$state.go`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) would likely be the method you would want to use in that case to navigate between nested views.

Comment: have to be careful where you add events like this to document so you don't compound them also

Comment: yes and I also should have used the updated jquery method and shown how to deregister - I've updated

Comment: `bind` is jQlite approach ... in case jQuery not being used in page. So was actually OK, and use `unbind`

Comment: fair enough - I typically have the full jQuery in my projects

Comment: Most people don't ... not a lot of need for it unless you are using plugins that aren't available as directives

Comment: sure you should strive to avoid using the full library if possible, but it's hard to find pure angular directives for all of your requirements so not sure what you mean by "most people" - I've found it to be somewhat unavoidable in large and complex business apps and note that angular now does not recommend against using the full version of jQuery ... you just need to make sure what you're doing the more outside of angular you get (e.g. understanding how `this` works and how it's managed by angular)

Comment: totally agree and I use it too in some apps, such as to integrate robust plugins like `fullcalendar` or even some DOM manipulation that helps improve performance of unnecssary watches. I mostly made those comments for others (and possibly OP) that may not be using it